# Would Zorquan be a Unity domain patron?

Tags: dnd-5e, cleric, unearthed-arcana, religions-and-deities, domains

Would ***Zorquan*** (Ancient Dragon god of dragonness, concerned only with the survival of dragons as a species) be a ***Unity domain*** patron deity of the draconic pantheon, as far as Cleric domains go?

It seems Lord Zorquan is attested in *only two* official canonical books *ever*: the 2e Forgotten Realms sourcebooks *Draconomicon* page 28, & *Cult of the Dragon* page 121 (also, name invoked by Malygris in writings on pages 63 & 119). No avatar or other stats are given, only a description in each book, as follows:

> **Zorquan** (ZORE-kwon)
>   (High One, Greatest Wyrm)
>   Deity of Dragonkind, Greater Power of the Prime Material Plane, Neutral alignment
>   Symbol: A black circle superimposed on a larger, concentric white circle
>   Although Zorquan is often described as the deity of dragonkind, he is really the deity of dragonness. As Corellon Larethian represents the central ideals of elvenkind, so does Zorquan represent the central ideals of dragonkind. He represents power, pride (which all dragons, even golds, have in abundance) and, most importantly, status. Although he is generally classed as neutral, Zorquan’s alignment would more properly be described as 'any'.
>   Zorquan is totally unconcerned with creatures other than dragons, except when their behavior affects dragonkind. He is the implacable enemy of any who would harm dragonkind (not, you will note, individual dragons). Adventurers who slay the occasional black or blue dragon will never feel Zorquan’s wrath. Members of all dragon species worship Zorquan.
>   He can manifest himself as a perfectly-formed version of any species of dragon. Whatever his form, his eyes crackle with sparks, sometimes spitting lightning bolts that flash and crack around his body. Zorquan is said to live somewhere on the Prime Material plane. Many legends tell of dragons with the temerity to visit his halls, but none give details on how to get there.
>   (*Draconomicon* pg28)

Later, a section detailing the draconic Holy Wars reads, in part:

> ~ Warfare tore through the ranks of dragon- kind, and at one time was violent enough to significantly deplete the Tori1 dragon population and actually threaten extinction unless something changed. Maybe it was the subtle influence of **Zorquan**, or maybe it was just that self-preservation finally came to outweigh the drives of fanaticism. Whatever the case, the dragons eventually turned away from the war, realizing that to follow their present course would lead to certain death for every dragon on the planet. ~
>   (pg29)

> **Zorquan**
>   (High One, Greatest Wyrm)
>   Zorquan is a neutral intermediate power of the Outlands. His portfolio is dragonkind and dragonness (the essence of that which is dragons), and his symbol is a black circle superimposed on a larger concentric white circle.
>   (*Cult of the Dragon* pg121)

As far as I have been able to determine, this is the *entirety* of canonical material provided on Zorquan!

I did find one webpage detailing a homebrewed stat-block & church for Zorquan, complete with an extensive subclass description for his Exemplars, at: [blog.aulddragon.com/2015/04/zorquan-the-high-one](http://blog.aulddragon.com/2015/04/zorquan-the-high-one)

I find the homebrew content from *AuldDragon* quite acceptable, though I don't plan on roleplaying it directly, since it is homebrew & we're playing a fairly by-the-book **5e campaign**.

**Given the information available, does it make sense that Cleric characters with Zorquan as their Patron would most aptly be classed under the [Unity domain](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/UA2020_02_06_Subclasses2.pdf)?**

If there is another more appropriate domain, or if I'm doing this entirely wrong, please inform me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Either Zorquan or Tamara could be ok with Unity domain clerics

This is a somewhat opinion-based question, and it is best answered by your own DM. However since it appears to be well-formulated, and given the lack of any further information on Zorquan, I will attempt to answer in a least subjective way based on the available data. (Zorquan is not mentioned in 3.5e and 4e *Draconomicons*. Neither is he present in *[Dragons and their Deities](https://archive.org/stream/DragonMagazine260_201801/DragonMagazine086#page/n37/mode/2up)*, the only article that the Dragon magazine [index](http://www.aeolia.net/dragondex/articles-subject.html) lists under the title "Dragons, Gods of".)

[Unity domain](https://www.dndbeyond.com/subclasses/unity-domain-ua) is UA material. Its description is as follows:

> A sense of oneness shines at the heart of healthy communities, whether bound together by friendship, blood, faith, or some other uniting force. The gods of unity deepen such bonds and delight in their strength.

When we look at the example deities of this domain, we see that only one deity has been chosen per pantheon and these are not the heads of pantheons but some intermediate deity whose portfolio covers wisdom (Angharradh), hearth, home, (Berronar Truesilver, Boldrei) or peace at home (Cyrrollalee, Eldath). Yet, this pattern is not strict. For example, from the Norse pantheon we see Heimdall, while arguably Frigga would be a better fit as she is the [goddess of birth and fertility](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-b-gods-of-the-multiverse#Fantasy-HistoricalPantheons), and is traditionally [the consort of Odin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frigg). It looks like stern protection of a community as a whole is also acceptable, which explains Heimdall and Gaerdal Ironhand.

With this perspective, let's look at Zorquan. He is not the head of the pantheon (that honour goes to Asgorath), and he cares about the race of dragonkind as a whole. And his influence is alluded to in establishing peace amongst dragons. Yet, as you quoted yourself, his portfolio mirrors that of Corellon (and not his consort Angharradh), it is not much about maintaining peace or family or hearth.

Can there be another contender for the Unity domain amongst the other dragon deities from the Draconomicon? Tamara, the Deity of Life and Light, comes somewhat close as she has the softening touch as the consort to a stern deity (Lendys) and she cares about "preservation of life and happiness". Thus she seems to be a decent fit for a dragon parenthood deity. This view is supported by the 3.5e *[Draconomicon](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/25831/Draconomicon-The-Book-of-Dragons-35?language=de&it=1)*, which lists "Family" as a portfolio for Tamara (page 35). (Unfortunately Zorquan is not mentioned in that book.)

At this point, it is up to your DM to decide. I personally wouldn't mind giving the Unity domain to Zorquan if I were DMing. However, as a sidenote I have to add that I would only allow dragon (and maybe the very exceptional dragonborn) priests of Zorquan as:

> Zorquan is totally unconcerned with creatures other than dragons, except when their behavior affects dragonkind.

Comment: So, going on what little information it appears we have to go on regarding the Domains of _draconic_ pantheons (Why was this left out? Are they listed & I missed it?), do you think Tamara is *more* appropriate as the draconic patron of the Unity Domain, or is she too busy with Life & Light since those are Domains as well? (Seems like having one Patron for multiple Domains has been avoided thus far?) Is it worthwhile to ask the larger question "Who are the Patrons of each Domain among the draconic pantheons?"

Comment: @ProphetZarquon: You should probably ask these as separate questions, as comments are not meant for extended discussions. However, even when you ask them as separate questions, the format of rpg.se will likely cause them to get closed, as the question "whether Tamara is more appropriate" is quite subjective. It might be better to talk about it with your DM.