# Are there any other published attestations of Zorquan, besides Draconomicon (1990) & Cult Of The Dragon (1998)?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, forgotten-realms, religions-and-deities, adnd-2e, dragons

I haven't found any mention of Zorquan, draconic god of "dragon-ness" (perhaps most famed as a critic of the draconic holy wars), except the two books *Draconomicon* (1990), & *Cult Of The Dragon* (1998).

Information found there is scant, but old campaign notes I've seen bore enough similarities, to make me wonder if some other publication from that time, mentioned Zorquan?

Looking for *any* published sources:  Modules, novels, magazines, videogames, comics, Spelljammer (or even Pathfinder?) modules or other material from other franchises, literally anything that might have been printed with the name "Zorquan" in it.

Is there any other Zorquan-related material, beyond the entries in these two books?

Comment: Pathfinder is a kind of bizarre suggestion here, since it is published by Paizo and the copyright for _Draconomicon_ and _Cult of the Dragon_ are owned by Wizards of the Coast—it would be a clear copyright infringement for Pathfinder to use the character.

Comment: Related [Would Zorquan be a Unity domain patron?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/169939/would-zorquan-be-a-unity-domain-patron)

Comment: I can't remember if it mentions Zorquan by name, but 5e's Fizban's Treasury of Dragons makes it clear that all draconic deities ate actually just Greatwyrms.

Comment: @Jack Are you implying that I've duplicated my own question?  ;D

Comment: @nick012000 Fizban's doesn't mention Zorquan, disappointingly. (I fear that in the modern age of Faerun, Zorquan may be "forgotten", with all that implies.) I've noticed 5e's downgrade of draconic deities (though I don't really get why that's a fun change to make)... Perhaps most pertinently, I don't know what happens to patron Greatwyrms when they're forgotten; as opposed to forgotten/”dead" gods? Might Zorquan still be hanging out somewhere in the Prime Material (had a lair there), or an Outer Plane, or the home plane of some god sharing some affinity? Just a body of thoughts in the Astral?

Comment: Essentially, if Zorquan underwent apotheosis & their Material form "died", even those sub-deific draconic 'deities' still undergo the process of their essence drifting in the Astral plane, correct? As I understand it, this Astral essence continues even for "forgotten" gods, & new items/places imbued with their influence, can be formed from this remnant essence? ===== Regardless of what happened to Zorquan by now, I'd like to be as comprehensive as possible, in gathering relevant published content. I feel Zorquan likely originated with some play-testing session or privately published campaign?

Comment: @KRyan I seem to recall quite a bit of overlap with Pathfinder modules & content, often using terms or generalized content popularized by AD&D or 3.5e; somehow, I just have this weird feeling there might have been something. The other which occurred to me, was Spelljammer. Overall, the Zorquan sections I've found, read as if they're in tribute to someone's game session/campaign?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Monster Mythology

In DMGR4 *Monster Mythology* p.128 there's a brief mention of Zorquan:

> The accessory *FOR1, Draconomicon*, lists draconic deities of the Realms on pp. 25-28. Some of these will be specific Realms deities, whereas others may be seen as aspects of the deities included in this book (e.g. Asgorath and **Zorquan may easily be seen as aspects of Io**, Null is an aspect of Chronepsis, etc.)

#### Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting (1993)

In the AD&D 2nd edition *Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting* boxed set, in *Running the Realms* p.63-64, "Other Nonhuman Deities":

> The dragons maintain a large and diverse pantheon. Not all dragons worship all the dragon gods, as not all humans worship all human gods. **Zorquan is the god of "dragonness", the state of being a dragon**, and there are gods of justice (Xymor), acquisition (Astilabor Hoardmistress), humor (Hlal the Jester), and other draconian ideals. Most supreme of the dragon gods is Asgorath, who may be similar to Ao as a passionless, all-powerful over-power.

This is about all of it, other than FOR1 *Draconomicon* and FOR11 *Cult of the Dragon*, which you mentioned.

Comment: Hey wow, "may easily be seen as aspects of Io" is something I'd seen theorized, but hadn't seen backed by canon; & I didn't know Zorquan was mentioned in the FR 2e boxed set at all! 

*Thank you!* 
It's not much more to go on than we had (we could have guessed the Io affinity), but more is better, nonetheless. 

Short of non-canonical campaign\session material which is probably lost to unwritten memory, I think this is probably all of the attestation Zorquan's had. 

... SO FAR???  
] ; >